# ansible dynamic inventory errors out

Tags: python, dynamic, ansible

I'm trying to use dynamic inventory to run ansible play books. if i run ec2.py --list it works fine but when i export varaibles and run ping fails with below error

> ```
> export ANSIBLE_INVENTORY=$PATH/ec2.py
>       export EC2_INI_PATH=$PATH/ec2.ini
>       export PYTHONPATH=/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
>
>       cd $WORKSPACE/ansible
>
>     inventory list works. without any issues.
>     python  $path/ec2.py --list
>
>     but when i tried to ping dynamic inventory it fails. ec2.py with script plugin: problem running $PATH/ec2.py --list ([Errno 13]
> ```
>
> Permission denied)
>             ansible -m ping tag_name_instancename

Comment: Change the `PATH` variable name, I think it's conflict with the reserved variable.

Comment: i had the physcial path mentioned there. i'm not using varaible

Comment: `ANSIBLE_INVENTORY=$PATH/ec2.py` what is the value of `$PATH`?

Comment: i provided $PATH here to mask physical path. but i gave /home/../..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As specified by [the fine manual](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/user_guide/intro_dynamic_inventory.html#inventory-script-example-aws-ec2):

> ... use Ansible’s -i command line option and specify the path to the script **after marking it executable**

It ran for you because you called `python` with the script as an arg. It should also work if you `./ec2.py --list`, since that's what ansible is going to do, too

Answer (score 0):

Run the script like,

$ ./ec2.py --list

For proper setup of dynamic inventory, I will suggest you taking reference from this link.
[dynamic-inventory](https://askops.in/run-ansible-playbook-through-bastion-host-dynamic-inventory/)